# Why is the $\theta$-term sometimes proportional to $g_s$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, axion

In [some](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.02669.pdf) [sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_CP_problem), the CP violating $\theta$-term is written as
$$  \frac{g_s^2 \theta}{32\pi^2} F \tilde F \, ,$$
while [others](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0011376) write it as
$$  \frac{ \theta}{16\pi^2} F \tilde F $$ 
[or](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.3908.pdf) 
$$  \frac{ \theta}{32\pi^2} F \tilde F \, .$$
What's the reason for these different prefactors? In particular, why do some presentations include the corresponding coupling constant $g_s$, while other don't?

Comment: Some people scale $A$ (and hence $F$) by a factor of $g$. Also, note that $\text{tr}(T^a T^b) = \delta^{ab}/2$ in standard normalization. Therefore, the expressions $\text{tr}(F\tilde{F})$ and $F^a \tilde{F}^a$ differ by a factor of $2$, but both would be written in abbreviated notation as just "$F \tilde{F}$".